# Div border with round corners

Tags: css, styles, stylesheet

How can I round the corners of a Div ?
I tried with following code but it doesnot work:

```
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 6px;
```

I am using IE6/7, so above code should not be an issue, still it is now working.

Any other work around ?

TIA.

Comment: IE < 8 does not natively support CSS `border-radius` property - see http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Comment: border-radius does not work in IE6, 7 or 8. If you want to see the resulting rounded borders you'll need IE9, Chrome, Firefox or Opera, or use a JavaScript fallback like CurvyCorners.

Comment: no one uses `IE6` and barely anyone uses `IE7`

Comment: "I am using IE6/7, so above code should not be an issue...", you must be trolling, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `border-radius` CSS property is not supported by IE6/7
You need to use a .htc file to achieve that effect in IE.

Here is the .htc file link: http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/downloads/detail?name=border-radius.htc

You need to upload the file to the /css/ folder on your website.
And here is how you would use it in your code:

```
.rounded-corners {
    behavior: url(/css/border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

This tutorial explains it in detail: http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers

Answer (score 2):

As cassi.lup just mentioned, rounded corners are not supported in IE6,7,8 .

You could however solve this with [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/)